# Need help creating a GCP Machine Image using GCP Python Libraries

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to create a new machine image from a .tar.gz file in one of my storage buckets. Doing this through the console is easy enough, but I need to do this programmatically with Python for a project I'm working on.

I've found what I think is the correct sections on how to create the machine image, but without examples I'm a little lost. I am fairly new to Python to still learning. I looks like I can use the Class "MachineImagesClient" and the "insert" method to make this happen.

If anyone can give me a bit of an example of where to start it would be much appreciated.

https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/compute/latest/google.cloud.compute_v1.services.machine_images.MachineImagesClient#google_cloud_compute_v1_services_machine_images_MachineImagesClient_insert
[2](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/compute/latest/google.cloud.compute_v1.types.MachineImage)

Comment: You're in the right path but to help you first try something and then comeback with any specific questions about your code. As well you can start here https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/insert#examples

Comment: Based from the official documentation for [Import machine images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-images/import-machine-from-virtual-appliance#import-image-from-appliance), the supported file format for Machine Images is OVA or OVF, while [Manually importing boot disks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/import-existing-image#requirements_for_the_image_file), does support the tar.gz.
Do note that Machine Images and Custom Images are of different types in GCP.

Comment: @FerreginaPelona thank you. I'll do a little more reading and start with the API Explorer.

Comment: Hi @FerreginaPelona, I would appreciate it if you could provide a Post Your Answer to assist the community with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Hurray! I was able to successfully create my image from the tar.gz file within my storage bucket. Thanks for the help everyone.

```
from pprint import pprint
import os
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

#Path to service account credentials JSON file for authentication
srvc_cred_path = "C:/pathtoserviceaccountcreds.json"
credentials = os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = srvc_cred_path

service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1')

# Project ID
project = 'my_project_id'  

#Parameters for the new image- name, container type, and source path
image_body = {
  "name": "test-image",
  "rawDisk": {
  "containerType": "TAR",
  "source": "URL to my bucket containing the tar.gz file"
  }
}

#Send the request
request = service.images().insert(project=project, body=image_body)
response = request.execute()

pprint(response)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily an answer, but an important step. I was able to follow guidance from @Ferregina and create a custom image with the API Explorer. I was able to use a tar.gz file from my storage bucket and define it in the request parameters. The API Explorer gives an example in JavaScript after it successfully complete so my next step is to try and adopt that to Python. I will update the post once I have something. [image: screenshot]